# Typescript Prisma Object.assign on select property with variable keys

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have a getFirm function that makes a Prisma query for a Firm object. The first argument for the function is the id of the firm and the second argument is an array of strings that represent the relations I'd like to include in this particular query.

```
export const getFirm = async <T extends keyof Prisma.FirmInclude>(
  id: string,
  relations: T[] = []
) => {
  try {
    const scalarFields = {
      id: true,
      name: true,
      created: true,
      featured: true,
      tagline: true,
      bio: true,
      website: true,
      logo: true,
      capabilityStatement: true,
      types: true,
      pocName: true,
      pocEmail: true,
      pocPhone: true,
    } satisfies Prisma.FirmSelectScalar;

    const relationObj = {} as {
      [Key in T]: true;
    };

    relations?.forEach((key) => {
      relationObj[key] = true;
    });

    const firmSelect = Object.assign({}, relationObj, scalarFields);

    const firm = await prisma.firm.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: parseInt(id),
      },
      select: firmSelect,
    });

    if (!firm) return null;

    firm.logo = firm.logo
      ? await getPresignedUrl(firm.logo, "firm-logos")
      : null;

    firm.capabilityStatement = firm.capabilityStatement
      ? await getPresignedUrl(firm.capabilityStatement, "capability-statements")
      : null;

    return firm;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return null;
  }
};
```

The type of the query result gets all screwed up and I'm seeing an error stating that firm.logo does not exist on the object despite it being clearly in the query. The problem seems to be related to this part, specifically:

```
const relationObj = {} as {
      [Key in T]: true;
};
```

In my head I've defined the list of strings that Key could be, which doesn't clash with the scalar fields keys I'm merging into the eventual select object, but I'm not fully understanding why having a variable there prevents Typescript from being able to figure out what the list of possible keys of the resulting object could be. Still somewhat new to Typescript and got very hung up on this.

I have tried using Omit-ing the scalar fields keys when defining T to give Typescript some sense that the generic type doesn't include the logo property but that doesn't seem to work.